# How can Apple patent flexi screens?

Tags: prior-art, apple, computer-graphics, samsung

According to my reading of http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/27/apple-patents-in-screen-speakers-flexible-displays-and-tactile-keyboards-for-future-iphones-and-ipads/, Apple patented flexi displays. How is this possible when they are already done by Samsung and LG? Has this patent been awarded already?

The patent is [WO/2012/129247](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2012129247&recNum=5&office=&queryString=FP%3A%28apple%29&prevFilter=&sortOption=Pub+Date+Desc&maxRec=7022?ystfuv), US 2012/029844.

Answer (score 1):

> has this patent been awarded already?

Nope. It has not been awarded. Apple has just filed the application and the application has got published. The patent itself is not granted. You can check it out [here](http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2012129247&recNum=5&office=&queryString=FP%3a%28apple%29&prevFilter=&sortOption=Pub%20Date%20Desc&maxRec=7022?ystfuv).
For the patent to be granted, after all the procedures, it takes few years.

> Can someone please tell me more about this.

Assuming you are asking about the patent filing process, [here](http://www.epo.org/applying/basics.html) you can find the general steps involved in obtaining a patent from the European Patent Office. You can check out USPTO website [here](http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/howtopat.htm) for similar information for the US.

It seems like the patent you have mentioned in the question is applied under PCT. So you can check the PCT procedure details [here](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/appguide/ipindex.jsp).

Comment: thank you for answering me. Can u tell me your opinion based on your experience if the patent is valid and if it will be accepted.

Comment: I remember Philips talking about flexible screens, something like 16 years ago!